# Problem loading million records in Salesforce using Bulk API

Tags: apex, integration, data, bulk-api

Hi I am loading some millions of data in Salesforce using Bulk API. Is there any limitation on that? The external system has failed to insert the records. Records is around 1 million.

Is there any setting I have to let external system know when they use the Bulk APi? Can any external system insert millions of record in salesforce. I have a full copy and enough space to store the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the volume of the data, external system will decide how they will proceed inserting data into SFDC.

**Bulk query limitations:**

> Batch Limit:

You can submit up to 10,000 batches per rolling 24-hour period. You can’t create batches associated with a job that is more than 24 hours old.

So, within 24 hours you can load 10K * 10K = 100,000K records

> Batch Size:

- Batches for data loads can consist of a single CSV, XML, or JSON file that is no larger than 10 MB.
- A batch can contain a maximum of 10,000 records.
- A batch can contain a maximum of 10,000,000 characters for all the data in a batch.
- A field can contain a maximum of 32,000 characters.
- A record can contain a maximum of 5,000 fields
- A record can contain a maximum of 400,000 characters for all its fields.
- A batch must contain some content or an error occurs.

Refer more on [Bulk API Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_bulkapi.htm)

Refer this example [Use Bulk Query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_using_bulk_query.htm) on how to insert data from external system using `BulkConnection` object of Partner API.

Comment: According to this the external system can push millions of records correct ? Dividing into batches will be taken care by sfdc? The ext says here just invokes the bulk API sending all the details  in this case

Comment: Yes, external system can push > 1 millon data, dividing into batches

Comment: @SfdcBat Just in case it wasn't clear, the *client* is responsible for upload CSV/XML/JSON files that contain no more than 10k records. Salesforce will automatically reject the file if you tried to upload a single file that contained 1 million records.

Comment: Yes , they tried inserting 400k record which was successful but could not insert 1 million. Seems like an error from external system side